# Vertically-centre content of a Table

Tags: tables

I can't figure out why some of the cells of this table are not correctly centered. Attached the source code. Thanks!

[image]

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}llc@{}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Known facts} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Open questions} & Objectives \\ \midrule
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The resistance to matrix cracking depends on\\ ply-thickness (also known as in-situ effect)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}There is no evidence of the in-situ effect under\\ out-of-plane shear\end{tabular} & \multirow{4}{*}{A} \\
            \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\\\\Out-of-plane (``transverse'') shear loads involve \\ shear cracks and delamination\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}There is controversy about which damage \\ mechanism triggers the other\end{tabular} &  \\
            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}There is controversy about which damage \\ mechanism   penalizes  the  load-carrying\\ capacity\end{tabular} &  \\
            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}There is no clear evidence of how ply-thickness\\ affects the damage sequence\end{tabular} &  \\ \midrule
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Thin-plies increase certain in-plane properties \\ because of the in-situ effect\end{tabular} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}There is little evidence of how thin-plies \\ respond to low-velocity impact loading\\ (particularly true for thin laminates)\end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{B} \\
            Thin-plies display brittle failure mechanisms &  &  \\ \midrule
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Interleaving polyamide non-woven veils may \\ enhance the impact resistance, tolerance and \\ interlaminar fracture toughness\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Few studies connect the microstructure and the \\ properties of interleaved systems\end{tabular} & \multirow{2}{*}{C} \\
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}The improvement comes with a penalty of\\ certain in-plane properties\end{tabular} & Few studies incorporate light non-woven veils &  \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}
```

Comment: With the proposed setting, it's rather ambiguous what the second paragraph in the left cell of the first row refers to in the center cell. Similar ambiguity is when you “center” the objective's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise against the usage of `adjustbox` in order to make the table fit into the textwidth. Also, you don't need all the nested tables and manual linebreaks if you use a `tabularx` environment as shown in the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering 
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXc@{}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Known facts} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Open questions} & Objectives \\ \midrule
            The resistance to matrix cracking depends on ply-thickness (also known as in-situ effect) & There is no evidence of the in-situ effect under out-of-plane shear & \multirow{10}{*}{A} \\
             & There is controversy about which damage mechanism triggers the other &  \\
           Out-of-plane (``transverse'') shear loads involve  shear cracks and delamination & There is controversy about which damage  mechanism   penalizes  the  load-carrying capacity &  \\
            & There is no clear evidence of how ply-thickness affects the damage sequence &  \\ \midrule
            Thin-plies increase certain in-plane properties  because of the in-situ effect & \multirow{4}{=}{There is little evidence of how thin-plies  respond to low-velocity impact loading (particularly true for thin laminates)} & \multirow{4}{*}{B} \\
            Thin-plies display brittle failure mechanisms &  &  \\ \midrule
            Interleaving polyamide non-woven veils may  enhance the impact resistance, tolerance and  interlaminar fracture toughness & Few studies connect the microstructure and the  properties of interleaved systems & \multirow{5}{*}{C} \\
           The improvement comes with a penalty of certain in-plane properties & Few studies incorporate light non-woven veils &  \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}%

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simpler, cleaner and more elegant solution: thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A commonly used convention in tables is that blanks mean repetition of the same entry in a given column, until countermanded by another value.

With the proposed setting, it would be rather difficult to understand what a paragraph in the left column refers to in the center column and similarly for the objective's code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering 

\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}

\small

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Known facts} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Open questions} & Objectives \\
\midrule
The resistance to matrix cracking depends on ply-thickness (also known as in-situ effect)
& There is no evidence of the in-situ effect under out-of-plane shear
& A
\\ \addlinespace
Out-of-plane (``transverse'') shear loads involve  shear cracks and delamination
& There is controversy about which damage mechanism triggers the other\par
  There is controversy about which damage  mechanism penalizes the load-carrying capacity\par
  There is no clear evidence of how ply-thickness affects the damage sequence
\\
\midrule
Thin-plies increase certain in-plane properties  because of the in-situ effect\par
Thin-plies display brittle failure mechanisms
& There is little evidence of how thin-plies respond to low-velocity impact loading 
  (particularly true for thin laminates)
& B
\\
\midrule
Interleaving polyamide non-woven veils may  enhance the impact resistance, tolerance and
interlaminar fracture toughness
& Few studies connect the microstructure and the properties of interleaved systems
& C
\\ \addlinespace
The improvement comes with a penalty of certain in-plane properties
& Few studies incorporate light non-woven veils
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this realization, the horizontal rules will make clear that “A” refers to everything in the first block, which might not be so evident if “A” is moved down, next to the long text in the second part.

It could be even clearer if the objectives are set at the left:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering 

\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}

\small

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cXX@{}}
\toprule
Objectives & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Known facts} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Open questions} \\
\midrule
A
& The resistance to matrix cracking depends on ply-thickness (also known as in-situ effect)
& There is no evidence of the in-situ effect under out-of-plane shear
\\ \addlinespace
& Out-of-plane (``transverse'') shear loads involve  shear cracks and delamination
& There is controversy about which damage mechanism triggers the other\par
  There is controversy about which damage  mechanism penalizes the load-carrying capacity\par
  There is no clear evidence of how ply-thickness affects the damage sequence
\\
\midrule
B
& Thin-plies increase certain in-plane properties  because of the in-situ effect\par
  Thin-plies display brittle failure mechanisms
& There is little evidence of how thin-plies respond to low-velocity impact loading 
  (particularly true for thin laminates)
\\
\midrule
C
& Interleaving polyamide non-woven veils may  enhance the impact resistance, tolerance and
  interlaminar fracture toughness
& Few studies connect the microstructure and the properties of interleaved systems
\\ \addlinespace
& The improvement comes with a penalty of certain in-plane properties
& Few studies incorporate light non-woven veils
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was also extremely helpful. Thank you very much for your help